# I am getting "error A2076: jump destination must specify a label" but it points to a line of code that executes a MACRO with nine parameters & no jump

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, macros, visual-studio-debugging

I am unable to identify the root cause of the error in order to fix it and so I'm looking for help with how to track down and fix the problem. I'm using VisualStudio 2022 Community as my IDE.   The same line of code is also causing two other errors, i.e., `error A2006: undefined symbol : 1` and `error A2077: instruction does not allow NEAR indirect addressing`.  The specific line of code identified by the assembler as erroneous is `CheckItemForDuplicates  TD17,TD27,TD37,TD47,TD57,TD67,TD77,TD87,TD97`.  This line of code is just one of nine similar lines of code in the procedure.  The procedure includes the following code:

```
CheckColumnsForDuplicates proc
invoke CopyCurrentState     ; For possible UNDO
RecordActionSteps ActionCode2   ;, CkColDUP
inc StepCounter
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD11,TD21,TD31,TD41,TD51,TD61,TD71,TD81,TD91    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD12,TD22,TD32,TD42,TD52,TD62,TD72,TD82,TD92    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD13,TD23,TD33,TD43,TD53,TD63,TD73,TD83,TD93    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD14,TD24,TD34,TD44,TD54,TD64,TD74,TD84,TD94    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD15,TD25,TD35,TD45,TD55,TD65,TD75,TD85,TD95    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD16,TD26,TD36,TD46,TD56,TD66,TD76,TD86,TD96    
CheckItemForDuplicates TD17,TD27,TD37,TD47,TD57,TD67,TD77,TD87,TD97
CheckItemForDuplicates TD18,TD28,TD38,TD48,TD58,TD68,TD78,TD88,TD98
CheckItemForDuplicates TD19,TD29,TD39,TD49,TD59,TD69,TD79,TD89,TD99    
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RET
CheckColumnsForDuplicates endp
```

There are two other similar procedures named "CheckRowsForDuplicates" and "CheckBoxesForDuplicates" both of which execute the "CheckItemForDuplicates" MACRO nine times, each time with a different set of nine parameters.  Consequently, it is not clear to me why this single line of code is identified as the cause of these errors and the other 26 similar lines of code are not also identified as the source of the same errors.

I've looked at the MACRO that is called by these three procedures to find any jumps or similar branching logic that might be the cause of the errors.  As background, the MACRO is a part of a larger program I have been working on as a means to learn and apply assembly language with Win32 API commands.  The program is intended to assist in solving Sudoku puzzles.  The MACRO contains two "FOR" loops.   The first "FOR" loop creates a bit MASK of Sudoku #s found in the 9 Sudoku cells that make up a row,column, or box in the Sudoku matrix and the 2nd "FOR" loop applies the inverse of the MASK to the remaining (unsolved) cells to identify DUPLICATES of the Sudoku #s found in the first "FOR" loop. In the first "FOR" loop, there is one "TEST" instruction with a corresponding "jz" instruction that includes s label "NextCell", which is LOCAL to the "FOR" loop.  In the 2nd "FOR" loop there is logic to apply the MASK which I originally setup to use offsets to copy data, but changed to direct copies (i.e., mov) in an effort to elminate the errors but the same errors still continued to occur.  I also searched the code for a "1" that somehow was being interpreted as an "undefined" symbol but found nothing that looked suspicious.  I tried disabling sections of code by "commenting them out" but I was unable to narrow down the source of the error to any specific code.  The MACRO I reviewed is:

```
CheckItemForDuplicates MACRO Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4,Cell5,Cell6,Cell7,Cell8,Cell9

; ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
; NOTES: An ITEM is either a Sudoku BOX, COLUMN or ROW..        
; ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
mov MASKITEM,0

;******************************************************************************************
FOR CellX, <Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4,Cell5,Cell6,Cell7,Cell8,Cell9>
Local CellX, NextCell
;******************************************************************************************
;This loop CREATES a MASK of Given, Solved and/or Guessed Sudoku #s found in the 9 MatrixCells of the item under review (i.e., row, column, or box)
    pushad                      ; Preparation steps: Save register values 

    mov ax, CellX           ; Copy CellX (e.g.,TD11) to working memory
    mov bx,ax               ; keep spare copy of CellX in register bx to test Input/Solved Flags 

    TEST bx,MASK InputDataFlag + MASK SolvedFlag            ; Check to determine if data is Input or Solved
    jz NextCell                                     ; If not Input or Solved Data, restore registers & process next matrix cell
                                                                                                ; Otherwise, data is Input/Solved Data. So, get value.
    AND ax, MASK DATABITS                                                   ; ... isolate value in the SPARE COPY of CellX previously copied into
                                                                                                ;     register ax in preparation steps
        ; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR N,  <1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>
    LOCAL N
    .IF ax==N
        OR MASKITEM,MASK @CatStr(<Possibility>,<N>)             ; Incorporate MASKs for all 9 cells of Item under review
    .ENDIF
    ENDM        ; End of For N loop
    ; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NextCell:
    popad
    ;******************************************************************************************
    ; If CellX value equals N, set MASK for ITEM to N
    ; Set Cell-1 MASK for ITEM-1 as described above. This MASK will incorporate
    ; ... ALL DUPLICATE POSSIBLITIES IDENTIFIED for the ITEM under review (i.e., Row,Col,Box)
    ;******************************************************************************************
ENDM        ; End of For CellX CREATE MASK loop         
;******************************************************************************************
;                           APPLY MASK
;******************************************************************************************
FOR CellX, <Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4,Cell5,Cell6,Cell7,Cell8,Cell9>
LOCAL CellX
; The combined MASK for the ITEM is applied to each of the 9 cells that the ITEM includes.
    pushad

mov ax,CellX
mov bx, MASKITEM
NOT bx
AND ax,bx
mov CellX,ax
    
;   mov ebx, offset CellX
;   mov eax,[ebx]
;   mov edx,offset MASKITEM
;   mov ecx,[edx]
;   NOT ecx
;   AND eax,ecx
;   mov CellX,ax                        ; ******* NOTE: CellX is NOT SOLVED until processed by ConfirmSudokuNumberFound MACRO *********

    popad
ENDM        ;End of For CellX Apply Mask loop

ENDM        ;End of CheckItemForDuplicates macro
```

In my limited experience debugging assembly errors, I usually find a misspelling, an extra random character, or a missing character (e.g., a period, comma, semicolon, etc.) but this one has me baffled.  I could use an expert's help in determining next steps in how to go about identifying and fixing the root cause of what to me is a mysterious error.

Comment: Use divide and conquer: keep making the program smaller while still getting that error.  Once it is miniature, you'll have a better view to what's happening.

Comment: If you put your complete set of files and commands you use to build on Github or some other online service I could take a look. But I agree with Eric. Start cutting stuff out until the problem disappears or changes. Often that process can also identify a minimal example of the problem.

Comment: As Erik says, a [mcve] of your error just needs to (not) assemble to narrow down the problem; it doesn't have to try to still run and do anything useful.  Like Michael says, literally just start deleting lines (in a copy of your file) until the error stops happening, then undo that last change; that line was relevant, so take out others.

Comment: Have you tried to generate a full listing file which might help find the error? Something like adding options `/Sf /Floutput.lst` to your `ml` command line. `output.lst` is the name of the list file you'd like to output to. It will be a text file you should be able to view in any text editor. If using VS 2022 you can right mouse click the project name and select `Properties`. Under the `Configuration Properties` you can select `Microsoft Macro Assembler` / `Listing File`. Change `List all Available Information` to `yes` (same as `/Sa`) and set `Assembled Code Listing File` to a file name

Comment: Ooops I meant _Something like adding options `/Sa /Floutput.lst` to your `ml` command line_

Comment: Thank you Eric, Peter, and Michael.  I'll try the divide and conquer approach and also see if I can generate a listing file to help identify the cause of these errors.  Thanks again.  I'll update you to let you know how it goes.

Comment: I created a LISTING FILE and it showed the offendng code causing the two A2076 errors as two individual instances of the "jz NextCell" instruction for the cases when "CellX" is "TD16" and "TD26".The LISTING FILE identified the "jz NextCell" for the case when "CellX" is "TD36" as the cause a "syntax error A2006 : 1".  Lastly, the LISTING FILE identified the "jz NextCell" as the cause of the " error A2077:instruction does not allow NEAR indirect addressing" for the case when "CellX" is "TD56".  None of the other 78 cases showed errors.  What do you think might cause these four to be different?

Comment: The assembly listing excerpt for the four errors can be viewed at https://pastebin.com/irvZ7vE9 .  Search for A2076. Search for A2077.  Search for A2006. You can also search for TD16 or TD26 or TD36 or TD46 or TD56 (which is error free).

Comment: In the 2nd prior comment "TD56" should have been "TD46".  That is, the 2nd to last sentence should be: The LISTING FILE identified the "jz NextCell" as the cause of the " error A2077:instruction does not allow NEAR indirect addressing" for the case when "CellX" is "TD46".

Comment: What version of MASM are you using? The one in Visual Studio or the one in MASM32 SDK? I ask about MASM32 because you tagged the question MASM32 which comes from here: https://www.masm32.com/ . Are you using MASM32 or is that just the wrong tag? As well to get our attention in a comment start our name with an `@`  and we can be notified.

Comment: @MichaelPetch .  That's a good question.  I originally was using MASM32 which was installled with WinASM but I started using VideoStudio to comple the code because WinASM seemed to have difficulty with the number and size of the files involved.  I honestly don't know what version of MASM VideoStudio runs.  How can  check this and is there a way to have it run MASM 32?

Comment: Thank you for using the `@` to tag me, I did get notified of your last comment. When you install Visual Studio 202x there should be a series of entries in the Windows menu one of which is a folder `Visual Studio 2022` and inside that there should be something like `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022`. Open up a command prompt and type `ml` and hit enter. That should return back the version of MASM (ML) being used.

Comment: @MichaelPetch .I found the Visual Studio Command Prompt option under the Tools menu in Visual Studio 2022 Community. I selected it and entered "ml" at the command prompt.   It showed "Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.34.31937.0. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. ... "  Does that explain the unexpected behavior?

Comment: No, it doesn't explain the unexpected behaviour but it eliminates a possibility. If you made all your code available somewhere (ie: Github) for all the source files and the command you use to assemble/link to an executable I might be able to take a closer look. The version of ML you seem to be using is the latest one in VS 2022 and not the one in MASM32 (Which is an old 6.xx version)

Comment: @MichaelPetch -- Will do.  Probably later this afternoon.  I'll let you know when I've got them uploaded.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  --  See LarryAlongi / _0001_SudokuAssistantGitHub01 at GitHub.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  --  I have used GitHub a only a couple of times.  So, I thought I should check in with you to confirm you can access the files that I uploaded and if there is anything else I should be doing.  Thanks.

Comment: I managed to finally find the zip file with stuff in it. At first I couldn't quite figure out where things were, but finally realized what you had done on Github. I'll take a look at this later tonight or tomorrow

Comment: @MichaelPetch -- Sorry about the confusion. I used the Drag-and-Drop option to upload the files and it appeared to create links to the files, which I thought was a little unusual.  I assume there is a different way to upload files which I need to learn how to use. I included 3 WORD documents.  One is a list of all the files. The other is a list of all the procedures & MACROs contained in each file. The 3rd is a description of the problem with information about where to find the 4 errors in the LISTING file, which I also attached.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  -- I'm curious if you've had a chance to look at code that I uploaded.  No rush.  Just wondering. Larry Alongi

Comment: Glad you reminded me, I forgot. I'll see what I can do in a little bit.

Comment: @MichaelPetch -- Did you have any time to take a look at the code I uploaded?